# Couldn't reach way point 1 error for HERE api

Tags: here-api

I am using this link
[Fleet Telematics API](https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=41.628944,-84.746896&waypoint1=41.629765,-84.763427&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-03-27T10:45:50&alternatives=1&weightPerAxle=8t&limitedWeight=40t&height=4.11m&width=2.59m&length=16.15m&trailersCount=)

but I am getting an error.

Couldn't reach way point 1 (start links -1022136892 -1022136890 -1022136876 -1022136875 1022136875 1022136876 1022136890 1022136892 dest links -1240614930 1240614930 )

Why is this happening? I provided valid coordinates.

Comment: I notice you are using an older version of the API. The current version uses a URL of this base, https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json. Can you try that?

Comment: I didn't realize there was a newer version of the API, unfortunately it's giving me the same error

Comment: Can you send me your updated api call, minus authentication of course.

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue with a few params taken off. Checking now. My gut tells me this is expected, that based on your request it CANT find a route, simple as that. For me it was limitedWeight.

Comment: After playing around with the parameters, I completely agree. It's giving this error because it cannot find a route (because of parameters). Just like you, I narrowed it down to the weight. 

If you still want the updated api call:

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=41.628939,-84.747024&waypoint1=41.629666,-84.762252&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=2020-03-27T17:18:05&alternatives=0&weightPerAxle=14t&limitedWeight=40t&height=4m&width=2.55m&length=16.5m&trailersCount=1

Comment: I'm going to post this as an answer and if you could accept it, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error (afaik) because the parameters are strict enough to not be able to find a route. It looks like the limitedWeight parameter is the one causing it to return this.